Fundamental group of $\operatorname{Ham}(M,\omega)$ and higher homotopy groups
Given a symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$, what do we know about $\pi_1(\operatorname{Ham}(M,\omega))$? What about higher homotopy groups?

Are you aware of Y. Savelyev's thesis https://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.4510.pdf https://arxiv.org/pdf/0804.0059.pdf?

You might want to take a look at the book "The geometry of the group of
symplectic diffeomorphisms" by Leonid Polterovich, and specifically Section 7.2 named "The fundamental group" and the references therein.

There is a map from $\pi_k(\mathit{Ham}(M,\omega))$ to the $k-1$th Hochschild cohomology of the Fukaya category. When $k=1$, this is known as Seidel representation.
